# C# / SQL Server : "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" in just one application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string

I've been trying to find the exact issue to this for hours but so far I just can't figure out what might be wrong.

I have a WPF application trying to connect to a remote SQL Server using this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyDBEntities" 
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.MyDBModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.MyDBModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.MyDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=server1\instance1,56482;Initial Catalog=DB_MyTool;User ID=MyTool_admin;Password=MyPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

...and I get the following inner exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Well, I think we all know this problem and it's possible solutions: check if server is online (it's a datacenter by the way), protocols, TCP/IP, firewall,...

But here's the clue:

- I'm on a company network using strictly preconfigured clients
- One of those clients, the one I'm developing on, is able to connect to the server with this very application (I just copied the whole Project Solution to the other Clients)
- The error occurs on every other client, even with Admin rights
- I took the exact data from the connection string and successfully connected using Microsoft SQL Management Studio on the other clients (where the application does not work)
- I wrote a little console tool to test connectivity of "third party software" on the other clients, and it was successful too

This leads to a few conclusions:

- It can't be the server, because Management Studio can connect
- It can't be the application, because it works on another client
- it can't be the connection string, because i tested it with my little tool

So, can anyone tell me what the problem could be?

Either it's a weird mixture of both my app and the configuration of the clients or i am just totally stupid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the connection string wrapped in a configuration xml-tag and can be read at app start?

Comment: yes it is, and the connection string is working fine on my client: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
... (see above)
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: How are you getting your application on to the other clients? Could it be a case of a missing lib? Maybe try creating a click once app deployment to test?

Comment: i was thinking that, too. i compile the whole solution and copy the project folders, then execute the .exe from the debug folder. works just fine when using a local sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot.

The problem was that I changed the connection string in the .config file located at the project folder, but not the one in the \bin\Debug folder, where, of course, I started the .exe file from when testing it on one of the other clients.

Whenever I rebuild my solution on the computer I develop on, this .config file is being overwritten. Since I need another connection string on the developers computer, the used connection string couldn't possibly be proper on any of the clients. I never thought of checking the compiled app.config files.

I hope that leaving this here can someday help someone like me, desperately looking for someone to teach him how to use Visual Studio.

Thank you for your efforts nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

> it can't be the connection string, because i tested it with my little tool

Some tools take different connection strings for virtualized servers.

```
# This syntax works for my Python and Perl ODBC Drivers:
Data Source=server1\instance1;Port=56482;

# This syntax works for my JDBC jTDS driver:
Data Source=server1:56482;instance=instance1;
```

Perhaps you may want to try the JDBC syntax?

Comment: thank you! well, i wrote the tool myself so it works just the way my application does. i'll test your syntax tomorrow!